# Calculation of proportion of zwitterion from this please.

Tags: acid-base

This is the question. I tried to post it in the title section but it was rejected because it was considered lengthy. Question: Valine is one of the 20 natural amino acids and has an acid -COOH (pka1=2.6) and an amine-NH2(pka2=9.6). If we consider a valine solution with pH=10.6, what is the proportion (%) of the zwitterion form of the solution? A) 2.4 B) 3.6 C) 5.7 D) 9.1 E) 10.2. 
Sorry if this might be too elementary but I don't know how to solve this question. I need help, thanks.

Comment: Since this seems to be a homework question, let me lead you along the solution. What is a Zwitter ion? Consider the molecule as (H2N-R-CO-OH).

Comment: This is not a homework question. It'

Comment: It's a past medical entrance exam question from my country under the chemistry section in  2013. I came across the question while revising for the exam and didn't know how to appreciate it. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Ok for a zwitter ion the acid is deprotonated and the amine group is protonated, thus the molecule has no net charge. It is given that the pKa of the acid is 2.6 and the pH of interest is 10.6. That is so alkaline that virtually no molecules will have the acid group protonated. So the problem boils down to figuring of what percentage of the amine group molecules are protonated.

Comment: Hi. You can refer to the homework policy [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). The term "homework" is used more loosely here, as the link describes.

Answer (score 1):

(I shouldn't answer this because it is a homework question with no effort, but since someone posted a wrong answer I'm answering anyway)

Only the pK of 9.6 is relevant because the pH is 10.6; therefore, think of the situation as having just two species, zwitterion (acid) and negative (conjugate base).

Because pH is one unit above the pK, the ratio of acid to conjugate base is 1 to 10.

Ratio of acid to total is 1 to 11.

1/11 = 0.0909

Answer (score -1):

Proportion of zwitterion = pka amine : pka acid
                                           =9.6 : 2.6 
                                           =3.6923